# Undefined class datetime in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I´m trying to create a datetime select in flutter. I have the frontend but I need to create function to show date time selector. I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sFE8IQyv_c&feature=youtu.be) video but i don´t know why return

> Undefined Class 'Datetime'`

```
  DateTime date = new DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final Datetime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: date,
        firstDate: new DateTime(2010),
        lastDate: null);
    if (picked != null && picked != date) {
      print('date selected: ${date.toString()}');
      setState(() {
        date = picked;
      });
    }
  }
```

So anybody has idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo declaring your `picked` variable - should be `DateTime` with a capital T.